# How to use mysqli bind_result

Tags: php, mysqli

im trying to use mysqli with bind_result but all i get is null values. My `$stmt`

number of rows is greater than 0 so i do have some data in it.

I dont realy understand what value should come into `bind_result`

I have read at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

And they dont explain what should i put in the `bind_result`.

Should i put there the column names? if yes, as strings? how do i get my wanted values?

Here is my code thanks for helping:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE workout_name = ? AND user = ?"; 

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $workout_name, $user);

    $workout_name = "rytg";
    $user = "tomer";

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->bind_result($comment, $commented_user);

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    {
    $response["workouts"] = array();

        while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        // temp user array
        $workouts = array();

        $workouts["comment"] = $comment;
        $workouts["user"] = $commented_user;

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["workouts"], $workouts);
    }
```

}

Comment: You have **twice** more code than needed to test sole bind_result. **This is not the way to go**. You're hindering yourself, adding some error prone cod to obscure the testing result.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, sorry i dont understand you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only problem is **insufficient error reporting**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Just add these lines at the top of your code and you will be immediately informed of the exact problem with your code.

Note that on the production server you have to turn displaying errors off and logging on

Comment: This is why error reporting is so essential. There are infinite number of cases where an error message will save you a lot of time or even money.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have a working PHP installation next to me at the moment, so I can't verify it, but I believe you might have to bind both parameters and result before you execute the query, like so:

```
$workout_name = "rytg";
$user = "tomer";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $workout_name, $user);
$stmt->bind_result($comment, $commented_user);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm not too sure about `store_result()` either. I don't recall having to use it while retrieving the results, so you might want to try running your code without it and see what happens.

Comment: you cant do it. Its written in the offical document.